# Remove the Sort by dropdown completely, in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I want to remove the Sort by dropdown completely, in my WooCommerce installation.

http://cswpstage.hostworks.net/product-category/memorabilia/signed-photos/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the theme that you're using. There are two approaches, CSS and PHP.

I see on your theme you have already hidden it via CSS using

```
.sort-param-order, 
.sort-param-sort {
    display: none;
}
```

If you want to hide it with PHP, you need to look for the action which adds it and remove that action. A search for `woocommerce_catalog_ordering` will generally return the action you're looking for.

Here is how you remove it via standard WooCommerce:

```
<?php
/**
 * Remove sorting from WooCommerce.
 */
function thenga_remove_filtering() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 );
}
add_action( 'init', 'thenga_remove_filtering' );
```

And here is how you remove it from the Storefront theme:

```
<?php
/**
 * Remove sorting from Storefront.
 */
function thenga_remove_filtering() {
   remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 10 );
   remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 10 );
}
add_action( 'init', 'thenga_remove_filtering' );
```